# Option Strict On disallows late binding for DataGridView Row get cell item

Tags: vb.net

I want to get the value of a column in a DataGridView so that I can check whether it already exists or not.

I have a code here that I want to not get an error for the Option Strict On.

```
For Each row In materialsGridView.Rows
    If materialCB.Text = row.Cells("Material").Value Then
        flag = True
        Exit For
    End If
Next
```

row.Cells("Material").Value says Option Strict On disallows late binding.

Comment: Can you stop using the strict on option?

Comment: It is for my project in class and the Professor required it so no.

Comment: Do you understand what Option Strict actually does? I'm guessing not. Maybe the first thing to do would be to find out.

Comment: I do understand it, I just want a way to get around this problem caused by late binding.

Comment: @LajosArpad: don't suggest this, it is highly recommended to use option strict and option explicit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You need to cast the `Rows` property to `DataGridViewRow`
2. `Text` returns a `String` and `Value` returns `Object`. So you have different types that you compare with `=`. That does not work with `Option Strict`. So one way to fix is to use:

---

```
For Each row As DataGridViewRow In materialsGridView.Rows
    If materialCB.Text = row.Cells("Material").Value.ToString() Then
        flag = True
        Exit For
    End If
Next
```

Another way would be to use `Equals`:

```
For Each row As DataGridViewRow In materialsGridView.Rows
    If materialCB.Text.Equals(row.Cells("Material").Value) Then
        flag = True
        Exit For
    End If
Next
```

Comment: The problem is row.Cells is a late-bound. So it still shows an error.

Comment: @roniearnibal Did you see Tim's update to the answer shortly after your comment?